# How to retrieve unique data from Mysql database table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with four columns namely `core`,`domain`, `Prog_StdName`, `LP_Prj_Desc`.

I want to retrieve unique the data, where `LP_Prj_Desc` column is dependent on `Prog_StdName` and `Prog_StdName` is dependent on `domain`, and `domain`, is dependent on  `core.

Below image which Ihave tried using the select statement.

```
SELECT `core`,`domain`,`Prog_StdName`,`LP_Prj_Desc` 
FROM `cf_ls` 
WHERE `core` <> 'PS'
```

this show the duplicate rows   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKXEl.png)

Actually I need to retrieve the data like below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYijn.png)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct `core`,`domain`,`Prog_StdName`,`LP_Prj_Desc` 
FROM `cf_ls` 
WHERE `core` <> 'PS' ;
```

Try this one

Comment: If it works, then mark correct answer and vote up. if not then do let me know about your expectation.